EF Core .ToJson() Owned Entities and ChangeTracking
I'm working on making the switch from the legacy PostgreSQL JSON column mapping from:
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public CustomerDTO Customer { get; set; }
}

to the newer owned .ToJson() on the model builder. This is going well; however, I also overwrite my SaveChanges() method to populate my outbox with entities to be pick up by message handlers.
The issue is if I modify my Customer object, the Order object is not marked as modified; however, the Customer object is. Is there an easy way without traversing navigation properties to get to the "parent"? In my outbox, I want the whole Order entity if any part is changed.
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var entityEntries = base.ChangeTracker.Entries();

    foreach (var e in entityEntries)
    {
        if (e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            // Add to Outbox
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}


The following post (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/33442) has the answer.
public static bool IsModified(this EntityEntry entry)
{
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Deleted) return false;
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified) return true;

    var tableName = entry.Metadata.GetTableName() ?? "";

    var hasInnerChanges = entry.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                            .Any(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged &&
                                        x.Metadata.GetTableName() == tableName &&
                                        x.Metadata.IsOwned() &&
                                        x.Metadata.IsInOwnershipPath(entry.Metadata));

    return hasInnerChanges;
}

